# How to apply SSE to an array whose length is not guaranteed to be multiple of 4?

Tags: c, optimization, vectorization, sse

I am currently working with some function like below:

```
 void vadd(float * a, float * b, int n){
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         a[i] += b[i];
     }
 }
```

This loop essentially can be rewritten using SSE but my question is how to handle the few elements that are left out if n is not a multiple of 4?

Thanks a lot,
Bob

Comment: Have you considered padding with zeros until you have a multiple of 4?

Comment: @roybatty doesn't that make it slower because you have to reallocate some memory for the array?

Comment: Not if you do your allocations with that in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle the last `n % 4` elements with a separate loop:

```
void vadd(float *a, float *b, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < n - n % 4; i += 4) {
        a[i + 0] += b[i + 0];
        a[i + 1] += b[i + 1];
        a[i + 2] += b[i + 2];
        a[i + 3] += b[i + 3];
    }
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] += b[i]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: note however that you can simplify `for (; i < n - n % 4; i += 4)` to `for (; i < n - 3; i += 4)`